Invalidate a tip in a TipGroup
A Tip in TipKit can be invalidated to not appear more with the func invalidate(reason: Self.InvalidationReason). This can be used after an user does something or a value under observation is changed.
However when the tip is on a TipGroup I cannot see a good way to invalidate it.
For example in this group:
    @State var tipGroup = TipGroup(.firstAvailable, {
        FirstTip()
        SecondTip()
        ThirdTip()
    })

How can invalidate the second tip when is not needed, like after pressing this button?
Button("Second Tip Button") {
    //Do something

}
.popoverTip(tipGroup.currentTip as? SecondTip)

My idea was to await the tip to be available and invalidate it, like the following code, but for Swift 6 that is not allowed...
Button("Second Tip Button") {
    //Do something

    //Invalidate tip
    Task{
        await tipGroup {
            $0 is SecondTip
        }?.invalidate(reason: .actionPerformed)
    }
}
.popoverTip(tipGroup.currentTip as? SecondTip)


Try this instead:
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

struct ContentView: View {
@State private var activeTip: TipIdentifier? = .secondTip

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Second Tip Button") {
            if activeTip == .secondTip {
                // Update the state to invalidate the second tip
                activeTip = nil
            }
        }
        .popoverTip {
            TipGroup(.firstAvailable, {
                FirstTip()
                SecondTip()
                ThirdTip()
            })
            .currentTip { tip in
                if let tipIdentifier = tip.identifier, tipIdentifier == .secondTip {
                    activeTip == .secondTip ? tip : nil
                } else {
                    tip
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}

enum TipIdentifier {
case firstTip
case secondTip
case thirdTip
}

extension Tip {
var identifier: TipIdentifier? {
    switch self {
    case is FirstTip:
        return .firstTip
    case is SecondTip:
        return .secondTip
    case is ThirdTip:
        return .thirdTip
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
}


And how can I make the the first tip of the tip group apply to another widget on the view? The tipGroup needs to be "outside" of the views.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

You can use Tip casting within the action of the Button.
import SwiftUI
import TipKit

struct FirstTip: Tip {
    var title: Text {
        Text("First tip")
    }
}

struct SecondTip: Tip {
    var title: Text {
        Text("Second tip")
    }
}

struct ThirdTip: Tip {
    var title: Text {
        Text("Third tip")
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tipGroup = TipGroup(.firstAvailable) {
        FirstTip()
        SecondTip()
        ThirdTip()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group {
                Button("First") {
                    if let tip = tipGroup.currentTip as? FirstTip {
                        tip.invalidate(reason: .actionPerformed)
                    }
                    // other code
                }
                .popoverTip(tipGroup.currentTip as? FirstTip)
                
                Button("Second") {
                    if let tip = tipGroup.currentTip as? SecondTip {
                        tip.invalidate(reason: .actionPerformed)
                    }
                    // other code
                }
                .popoverTip(tipGroup.currentTip as? SecondTip)
                
                Button("Third") {
                    if let tip = tipGroup.currentTip as? ThirdTip {
                        tip.invalidate(reason: .actionPerformed)
                    }
                    // other code
                }
                .popoverTip(tipGroup.currentTip as? ThirdTip)
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}



To invalidate a specific tip within a TipGroup in Swift, you need to make sure you're targeting the right tip and handling its invalidation properly. In your code, it looks like you want to invalidate the SecondTip when a button is pressed.
But, TipGroup does not provide direct methods to invalidate specific tips inside the group. Instead, you need to manage the state of the tips yourself, especially if you want to invalidate a specific one based on certain conditions.
To fix this:
First, track tips using state or identifiers: Maintain a state or identifier for the tips you need to manage. This will help you reference and invalidate them later.
Invalidate specific tips: Use the state or identifier to find the specific tip you want to invalidate.
import SwiftUI

import TipKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tipGroup = TipGroup(.firstAvailable, {
        FirstTip()
        SecondTip()
        ThirdTip()
    })

@State private var showSecondTip = true

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Second Tip Button") {

            if showSecondTip {
                Task {
                    let tipToInvalidate = tipGroup.tips.first { $0 is SecondTip }
                    if let secondTip = tipToInvalidate as? SecondTip {
                        secondTip.invalidate(reason: .actionPerformed)
                        showSecondTip = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .popoverTip(tipGroup.currentTip as? SecondTip)
    }
}

Hope this answer helps.

Unfortunately, for now, TipGroup doesn't seems to expose a tips property were we could find the right Tip. Were did you found it on the documentation?

You're correct that TipGroup in TipKit doesn't directly expose the tips it manages. This limitation means you have to manage the state of tips and their invalidation manually if you need to control specific tips within a group. Let me post another answer to better help with this.
